# IOS Second App - + Button disappeared

Tags: ios, xcode

Im new to IOS app programming - I went though the [iOS second app tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/) (the bird sighting one) and I have 2 issues when I get to the end and any pointers would be most appreciated.

1. The + button on the main view has disappeared and I dont understand why? Which part of code governs this?
2. When selecting the pigeon bird in the main view, the detail view comes up but with detail still in all the items, so Bird Name is still detail, location is still detail etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Edit - Added the .h and .m code for the masterviewcontroller

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class BirdSightingDataController;
@interface BirdsMasterViewController : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) BirdSightingDataController *dataController;
- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
- (IBAction)cancel:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "BirdsMasterViewController.h"

#import "BirdsDetailViewController.h"
#import "BirdSightingDataController.h"
#import "BirdSighting.h"
#import "AddSightingViewController.h"

@implementation BirdsMasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.dataController = [[BirdSightingDataController alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.accessibilityHint = @"Adds a new bird sighting event";
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.dataController countOfList];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BirdSightingCell";

    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
    if (formatter == nil) {
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    BirdSighting *sightingAtIndex = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:sightingAtIndex.name];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[formatter stringFromDate:(NSDate *)sightingAtIndex.date]];
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return NO;
}

- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ReturnInput"]) {

        AddSightingViewController *addController = [segue sourceViewController];
        if (addController.birdSighting) {
            [self.dataController addBirdSightingWithSighting:addController.birdSighting];
            [[self tableView] reloadData];
        }
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
- (IBAction)cancel:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"CancelInput"]) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowSightingDetails"]) {
        BirdsDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        detailViewController.sighting = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: You should include your code.

Comment: Hi, my code is now identical to the code given in the appendix of the tutorial - I'll add the code for the msaterviewcontroller (assuming the + button code should be in there?)

Comment: Ok, so I have figured out the add button query....  It because the self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem in the viewDidLoad no longer exists.....  But if anyone can offer any pointers on point 2 it would be appreciated.

Comment: Jamie, check the assignment of the **sighting** property in `prepareForSegue` where the `BirdsMasterViewController` "gives" the new specific bird data to the details view controller. Check to see if the sighting data is not nil at that time. You should also check `BirdsDetailViewController` for any errors in the custom setter for  the **sighting** property.

Comment: Thanks Aaron - I`ll look there tonight.  I did another tutorial last night that spent smoe time on the prepareForSegue so it seems to reasonable place to look..  Thanks

Comment: Aaron - you were correct the place to look was the prepareForSegue - for some reason it wasnt picking up the segue identifier so wasnt setting up the sighting..  Problem Solved